# API Time zone difference problem

Tags: support, api, documentation, c#, .net

I am writing a .NET application with the Stack Exchange API (using the Stacky library) and I am using it to ask the server for some questions that occured in the last hour. However, I and the server are not in the same time zone, so if I ask it for questions from `DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1)` to `DateTime.Now`, it gives me questions from 9 hours ago to 8 hours ago.

This is obviously a problem. Right now I am getting over it by asking for questions from `DateTime.Now.AddHours(7)` to `DateTime.Now.AddHours(8)`, but will obviously not work for people in other time zones. How can I compensate for the time difference in such a way that it will work for all users?

Comment: The API uses [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) for all methods / results. You need to find a way to get the current UTC time in C#. This would make an excellent question for [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com).

Comment: @George thanks, I thought questions about the API were supposed to go here.

Comment: They are and this is certainly an on-topic question. I just thought your C# question might get a quicker answer on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @George as it happens, a 2 second Google yielded `DateTime.ToUniversalTime`, so problem solved. If you copypaste that into an answer, I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I learned from George Edison in his comment, the server handles time in UTC format. Just replace your calls to `DateTime.Now` with `DateTime.UtcNow` or you can convert any `DateTime` to UTC format with the `ToUniversalTime` method. Just make sure not to call `ToUniversalTime` on the server's time, or it'll get messed up.